# Unable to connect to apache solr - process restart needed

Tags: performance, solr

I am facing a strange problem with solr. After running solr for few hours, client starts reporting error message that it is unable to contact the solr, although solr instance is up on the server. 
I can't see any high traffic on website which sometimes is the reason of connection refusal.

This issue gets fixed after solr restart.

Any idea what is going wrong here ?

Comment: you need to explain how your solr is deployed, to enable guys to help you better.

Comment: what do web server logs say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to most of the problems can be found in logs. Thanks D_K for reminding me.

SEVERE: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I have increased the heap size to fix this issue.

```
java -Xms<initial heap size> -Xmx<maximum heap size>
```

Also, we have reduced document size by removing unnecessary information which we don't need to retain in solr.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a client with long running connection but low amount of traffic, you may have a firewall in between. Firewalls have limited-size routing tables, so they eventually drop the mapping for connections they haven't seen for a while.

Try sending a ping query every 30 minutes or so through that specific connection and see if the issue goes away. If you need to validate it, run Wireshark on the client and see whether the client is getting RST (reset) packets from an unexpected end point (that would be firewall).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add your collection in solr by following the step given in this url ( https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95897/apache-solr-4-6-0-insta... ) and then select your collection from your solr which is running on localhost or live site (http://localhost:8983/solr/) and go to schema tab. Click schema tab and then you can see you schema file attach in apachesolr module.

You now just need to your schema url which just look like this http://localhost:8983/solr/your_core_name/. Now add this url in apachesolr module.

Then it will show that your site has contacted apache solr server in your drupal site.